# <anonymous> is used uninitialized in this function g++ 4.4

Tags: c++

While compiling with g++ 4.4, I am encountering this compilation error.

```
struct Class
{
    Class() { }
    void Method() const;
};

void f(); // undefined

void g( Class x ) // pass by value
{
    f();        // call undefined function
    x.Method(); // call method on parameter
}

void h()
{
    Class x;
    g( x );
}
```

While compiling using these flag:

g++ -Wuninitialized -O3 -c -o a.out test.cpp

test.cpp:22: warning: "anonymous" is used uninitialized in this function

And this is only encountered with g++ version 4.4.

Could anyone please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40146

Comment: Even after putting the code inside namespace wont resolve this problem.
Although, what I have noticed is (may be wrong) that when I pass the Class x by reference in function g(), warning disappears.
This may be absurd. What could be the proper solution.

Comment: `void Method() const` is missing the implementation. Adding a body to it made the warning vanish. However, the error message is a bit confusing.

Comment: Many methods are missing the implementation like f(). Thats why I was compiling with a -c flag.
I don't think this is the problem.